# Day numbering in Yelp API

Tags: api, yelp

When Yelp API returns data for each day of the week, like the hours when business is open, the first day is 0 and the last one is 6. Is it safe to assume that 0 corresponds to Sunday?

```
"hours": [
{
  "hours_type": "REGULAR",
  "open": [
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 0,
      "start": "1730"
    },
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 1,
      "start": "1730"
    },
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 2,
      "start": "1730"
    },
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 3,
      "start": "1730"
    },
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 4,
      "start": "1730"
    },
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 5,
      "start": "1730"
    },
    {
      "is_overnight": false,
      "end": "2200",
      "day": 6,
      "start": "1730"
    }
  ],
  "is_open_now": false
}
```

],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using latest api version (v3).
you can refer to the yelp api documentation 
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business which clearly says days 0-6 should be considered as **monday to sunday**

From the documentaion

> hours[x].open[x].day  int From 0 to 6, representing day of the week
>   from Monday to Sunday. Notice that you may get the same day of the
>   week more than once if the business has more than one opening time
>   slots.

Comment: Uh, glad I asked. I overlooked this. Thanks.